# Hash Binary Tree Map

Tags: java, tree, hash-map, hashcode

I made a map based on a binary tree ordered by hashcodes, with collisions fixed with `equals()`. Are there any improvements I could make?

```
public class HashTreeMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    Optional<Node<K, V>> root = Optional.empty();

    @Override
    public V put(final K key, final V value) {
        // Returns previous value associated with key

        if (root.isPresent()) {
            return root.get().put(key, value);
        } else {
            root = Node.createNode(key, value);
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public V get(final Object key) {
        if (root.isPresent()) {
            return root.get().get(key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        if (root.isPresent()) {
            return root.get().size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return !root.isPresent();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(final Object key) {
        // TODO a better method, this could easily be improved
        final Set<K> keys = keySet();
        return keys.contains(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(final Object value) {
        // TODO a better method, this could easily be improved
        final Collection<V> keys = values();
        return keys.contains(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(final Object key) {
        if (root.isPresent()) {
            return root.get().remove(key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(final Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (final Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
            put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        this.root = Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        // TODO a better method, this could easily be improved
        final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = entrySet();
        final Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>(entries.size());
        for (final Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            keys.add(entry.getKey());
        }
        return keys;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        // TODO a better method, this could easily be improved
        final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = entrySet();
        final List<V> values = new ArrayList<>(entries.size());
        for (final Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
            values.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        if (root.isPresent()) {
            final Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> set = new HashSet<>();
            root.get().addAllEntries(set);
            return set;
        } else {
            return new HashSet<>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tree{" + (root.isPresent() ? root.get().toString() : "") + "}";
    }

    private static class Node<K, V> {
        Optional<Node<K, V>> left = Optional.empty();
        Optional<Node<K, V>> right = Optional.empty();
        final int id;
        List<Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<>();

        public Node(final int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int size() {
            int leftSize = 0;
            int rightSize = 0;

            if (left.isPresent()) {
                leftSize = left.get().size();
            }
            if (right.isPresent()) {
                rightSize = right.get().size();
            }
            return entries.size() + leftSize + rightSize;
        }

        public V put(final K key, final V value) {
            V prevVal = null;
            final int idKey = key.hashCode();
            if (id == idKey) {
                final Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it = entries.iterator();
                // check for overlaps
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    final Entry<K, V> e = it.next();
                    if (e.key.equals(key)) {
                        prevVal = e.value;
                        it.remove();
                    }
                }
                entries.add(new Entry<>(key, value));
            } else if (idKey < id) {
                if (left.isPresent()) {
                    prevVal = left.get().put(key, value);
                } else {
                    left = createNode(key, value);
                    prevVal = null;
                }
            } else if (idKey > id) {
                if (right.isPresent()) {
                    prevVal = right.get().put(key, value);
                } else {
                    right = createNode(key, value);
                    prevVal = null;
                }
            }
            return prevVal;
        }

        public V get(final Object key) {
            final int idKey = key.hashCode();
            if (id == idKey) {
                final Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it = entries.iterator();
                // check for overlaps
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    final Entry<K, V> e = it.next();
                    if (e.key.equals(key)) {
                        return e.value;
                    }
                }
                // we found a matching hashcode, but no equal node
                return null;
            } else if (idKey < id) {
                if (left.isPresent()) {
                    return left.get().get(key);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                // hashcode is greater than current node
                if (right.isPresent()) {
                    return right.get().get(key);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        public V remove(final Object key) {
            final int keyId = key.hashCode();
            if (keyId == id) {
                final Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it = entries.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    final Entry<K, V> e = it.next();
                    if (e.key.equals(key)) {
                        it.remove();
                        return e.value;
                    }
                }
                // matching hashcode, but no matching equals
                return null;
            } else if (keyId < id) {
                if (left.isPresent()) {
                    return left.get().remove(key);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            } else {
                if (right.isPresent()) {
                    return right.get().remove(key);
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (final Entry<K, V> e : entries) {
                sb.append(e).append(',');
            }
            return (left.isPresent() ? left.get().toString() : "")
                    + sb.toString()
                    + (right.isPresent() ? right.get().toString() : "");
        }

        public static <K, V> Optional<Node<K, V>> createNode(final K key,
                final V value) {
            final Node<K, V> node = new Node<>(key.hashCode());
            node.entries.add(new Entry<>(key, value));
            return Optional.of(node);
        }

        public void addAllEntries(final Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>> s) {
            s.addAll(entries);
            if (left.isPresent()) {
                left.get().addAllEntries(s);
            }
            if (right.isPresent()) {
                right.get().addAllEntries(s);
            }
        }

        private static class Entry<K, V> implements Map.Entry<K, V> {
            private final K key;
            private V value;

            public Entry(final K key, final V value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }

            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return key + "=>" + value;
            }

            @Override
            public K getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            @Override
            public V getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public V setValue(final V value) {
                final V old = this.value;
                this.value = value;
                return old;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One little improvement you could make is that in several methods you have this structure:

```
if (condition) {
     ...
    return ...;
} else {
    ...
    return ...;
}
```

There is no need for the `else` statement. You can simply write:

```
if (condition) {
     ...
    return ...;
}
...
return ...;
```

A more drastic change would be rather than using `Optional`, you might consider using the "[Null Object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern)" design pattern. That is, create a `NullNode` implementation of (an interface) `Node<K, V>` that returns, for example, `null` for any `get()` and `0` for `size()`. This would eliminate *a lot* of conditionals and make the code significantly easier to read.

---

**Update:** As requested by David Harkness, I have knocked together an implementation based around a polymorphic Node object. I'm not saying this is necessarily a "better" implementation, but it just shows an alternative way of implementing the code that removes a large number of the conditionals.

Note: It's not a fully working implementation. It's just a gist. I haven't bothered implementing `remove` and if you `put` the same value twice it won't overwrite the original. I haven't done any testing on it, so it may be full of bugs. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to finish it off.

```
public static class HashTreeMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V> {

    private final Node<K, V> nullNode = new NullNode();
    private Node<K, V> root = nullNode;

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return root.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root.size() == 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return keySet().contains(key);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        return values().contains(value);
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return root.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        V previousValue = root.get(key);
        root = root.put(key, value);
        return previousValue;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> entry : m.entrySet()) {
            put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        return root.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        return root.values();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }

    private interface Node<K, V> {

        V get(Object key);

        Node<K, V> put(K key, V value);

        int size();

        Set<K> keySet();

        Collection<V> values();
    }

    private class NullNode implements Node<K, V> {

        @Override
        public V get(Object key) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Node<K, V> put(K key, V value) {
            return new ConcreteNode(key, value);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Set<K> keySet() {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<V> values() {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }

    private class ConcreteNode implements Node<K, V> {

        private Node<K, V> left = nullNode;
        private Node<K, V> right = nullNode;
        private final List<Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<>();
        private final int ourHash;

        public ConcreteNode(K key, V value) {
            addEntry(key, value);
            this.ourHash = key.hashCode();
        }

        private void addEntry(K key, V value) {
            entries.add(new Entry<K, V>(key, value));
        }

        @Override
        public V get(Object key) {
            int hash = key.hashCode();
            if (hash == ourHash) {
                for (Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
                    if (entry.key.equals(key)) {
                        return entry.value;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            } else if (hash < ourHash) {
                return left.get(key);
            } else {            
                return right.get(key);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Node<K, V> put(K key, V value) {
            int hash = key.hashCode();
            if (hash == ourHash) {
                addEntry(key, value);
            } else if (hash < ourHash) {
                left = left.put(key, value);
            } else {
                right = right.put(key, value);
            }
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return entries.size() + left.size() + right.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Set<K> keySet() {
            Set<K> keys = new HashSet<>();
            for (Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
                keys.add(entry.key);
            }
            keys.addAll(left.keySet());
            keys.addAll(right.keySet());
            return keys;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<V> values() {
            List<V> values = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
                values.add(entry.value);
            }
            values.addAll(left.values());
            values.addAll(right.values());
            return values;
        }
    }

    private static class Entry<K, V> {
        public final K key;
        public final V value;

        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Keeping the `else`, you don't have to read the body of the `if` block to see the either-or logic. This matters less for simple guard clauses, of course.

Comment: The Null Object pattern works better for data objects and unmodifiable results. Using it here would change the `isPresent` calls to `instanceof` checks in cases where you're modifying the tree. It may still pay off though since the classes have a lot more read methods.

Comment: Node is a private and internal, so you would be able to add an `isModifiable()` method to avoid having to use `instanceof`. Better yet, have a `Node modifiableNode()` method on NullNode that returns a new modifiable node or, for a real node, returns itself. No need for any conditional then. It's the beauty of polymorphism.

Comment: But you need to store the new modifiable node when switching from the null object or you'll lose the data value you just added. I don't see a way to get rid of the conditional entirely.

Comment: You store it every time.

Comment: I can see how that would work, but I suspect the code will be more confusing. Care to take a crack at demonstrating it in code?

Comment: Voilà. What do you think?

Comment: Very nice +1. Might I suggest `EmptyNode` in lieu of `NullNode`?

Comment: Yes, that would be a much better name.

Answer (score 0):

A tiny note: `Optional` is meant to be a return value only, *not a field*. It's not even `Serializable` because of this.

I see only disadvantages: While your code could perfectly work with Java 5 (after removal of diamonds, otherwise Java 7), it can't because of `Optional` (which unlike the diamonds is hard to remove). But actually, **I *always* see only disadvantages of `Optional`** but YMMV.

Note that your memory consumption and GC overhead sort of double and the speed sort of halves because of it (memory indirection is cheap when cached, but with a huge map or under memory pressure, it gets very expensive).